# How can I fix this bizarre "No such file or directory" error when building with make on Mac?

Tags: c++, node.js, macos, makefile, sh

I have a Node.js Native Addon C++ library, which uses `node-gyp` to generate a Makefile and then compiles and links the library using that Makefile. I am encountering this strange error: approximately once every 20 runs or so, a build fails with an error that starts with `sh:` and then says that a seemingly random system binary or shell builtin cannot be found in a seemingly random directory from the path. For example, a recent error message says this:

```
sh: /Users/kbuilder/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin/printf: No such file or directory
```

Here are some other variants I have seen:

```
sh: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/touch: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/kbuilder/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/bin/rm: No such file or directory
sh: /Users/kbuilder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin/printf: No such file or directory
```

Some other error messages that seem to be related are:

```
/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file
```

and

```
make: /bin/sh: Exec format error
```

What is happening here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Incorrect line endings in a text file somewhere?

Comment: If that is the problem it seems surprising that this would happen so infrequently and inconsistently. I still checked, and the only file committed in the repository with Windows line endings is a test input file that is definitely not involved in the build. I don't expect that any file generation on Mac is generating the wrong line endings.

Comment: What version of GNU make do you have?  Are you using the GNU make that comes with Xcode?  That is a very old, known to be buggy (and some of those bugs were added by Apple and don't exist in the original source for the very old version they ship) version.  I recommend you get a newer version of GNU make from homebrew or ports or build it yourself.

Comment: Installing make from brew actually seems to have fixed this. I just tried that and none of my builds have failed yet.

Comment: For what it's worth, our node-gyp build was also failing on Catalina and Xcode 12.1 (GNU Make 3.81) and upgrading the system to GNU Make 4.3 resolved the problem.